# Array increment at button click

Tags: java

i have take array `Arr_ActivityName_fack` & `Arr_ActivityName`
 like:

```
Arr_ActivityName_fack = new String[Arr_ActivityName.length];
```

but i need icrease array size when i click on button. so how can i do it?

Comment: Just reinitialize the array on button click! Did you try anything, any code available?

Comment: use dynamic-size structure as ArrayList.

Comment: This is a really bad question from a user that did not bother to put their real name (and email) that looks to have negative reputation.  Is this a school coursework question ?  What kind of button ?  Try clicking the power button on your computer that might do it and a sticky note with some instructions to remind the user to increase the array size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Collections like ArrayList or if that's not apropriate:

```
String[] tmp = Arr_ActivityName_fack;
Arr_ActivityName_fack = new String[Arr_ActivityName_fack.length + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i) {
    Arr_AktivityName_fack[i] = tmp[i];
}
```

Or have a look at the link to arraycopy in the comments.

Comment: Shh don't tell him about System.arraycopy() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29  JDK6 Arrays.copyOfRange()  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29

Comment: LTGTFY Let Me Google That For You -  "java copy array"  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Sorry, my first post was rubbish. But thank you for the link to arraycopy(). I programming java for quite some time now, but didn't know about this one...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Collection, like a List, instead of an array.  It's a more dynamic data structure.

Comment: i need icrease array size when i click on button.

Comment: You probably want to add a new instance to the List, which automagically bumps up the size.